# Error with executing query in visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

I created databese like *server exploler*/ *data connection* / *add connection* . *Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 (.NET Framework)* use *Create* and create my own *MyDatabes.sdf* file.

Now in *server exploler* right click on my databese --- and click on *new query*

.

Try run this:

```
Create table [student]
(
    [student_id] Bigint NOT NULL,
    [bornnumber] Varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    [branch] Integer NOT NULL,
    [specialization] Integer NOT NULL,
    [year] Smallint NULL,
    [studygroup] Varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    [started] Datetime NULL,
    [finished] Datetime NULL,
    [status] Char(1) NULL,
Primary Key ([student_id])
)
```

press execute query:

1. it shows table Query Definitions Differ wher is written

   "The CREATE TABLE SQL construct or statement is not supported."

   Click to conntinnous
2. Shows SQL Executation ERROR

   "Error Source: SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data PRovider Error Message: The specified data type is not valid.[Data type (if known)=Varchar]";

I hope query is fine... and I hope ADO,NET know Varchar. Please Do you know were is problem ?

using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`varchar(n)` is [indeed not supported on CE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424%28v=sql.100%29.aspx); only unicode `nvarchar(n)`, `nchar(n)` and `ntext`. Change to `nvarchar(10)`, `nvarchar(5)` and `nchar(1)`, etc.

Also; start with the simplest operation (table etc) that works - and keep expanding it until it breaks, then you'll know which bits fail.