# query to create a new table in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Actually, how to create a new table use query in database SQL Server 2008

I got a error when I try to execute my query

This is my code

```
 if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[FilesStore]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
 drop table [dbo].[FilesStore]
 GO

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FilesStore] (
     [FileId] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
     [OriginalPath] [varchar] (200) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
     [FileData] [image] NOT NULL 
 ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
```

I got this error message

> *The DROP TABLE SQL construct or statement is not supported
>
>   The CREATE TABLE SQL construct or statement is not supported.*

Anyone please help me

thanks

Comment: I think the important bit here is what isn't said - how are you executing the SQL? - it sounds like that has a "safety feature" preventing you from executing these DDL commands.

Comment: Can you show the code that is executing the query?

Comment: actually I just right click in the code and then click execute sql

Comment: Are you by any chance using SQL Server CE? If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242861/error-with-executing-query-in-visual-studio  ... (change varchar to nvarchar)

Comment: Can you please post the result of 'select @@version' command here?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this script and worked perfectly.

Do you have db_owner role?

Comment: really?? I have tried it for 10 times and the result still error...what's db_owner role???Actually I'm a newbie in c# and sql server

Comment: Yeah, the syntax of the script is fine. db_owner is the role required to perform these actions. Be sure that you are executing the script on the right DB. Also, which version of SQL 2008 are you using? Try to use this command and post the results exec sp_helpuser

Answer (score 0):

Permissions! You do not have sufficient permissions to execute CREATE or DROP.
Check the Security database role for your user on your database.

As DROP is not a grantable permission, people who can drop a table are:

- The dbo
- The owner of the schema
- The owner of the table (usually the schema owner but it can be
  changed to someone else)
- members of the db_ddladmin fixed database role members of the
  db_owner fixed
- database role members of the sysadmin fixed server role
- grantees of the CONTROL permission on the table or permissions that
  imply control on the table
- grantees of the ALTER permission on the schema or permissions that
  imply alter on the schema.

**Update:**
**How to add yourself as db_owner for your database?**

On the SQL Server Management Studio, go to the Security > Logins node for your SERVER in the tree.
Locate the creds that you use to connect to SQL Server, right-click Properties.
Click on User Mapping, check your database checkbox in the list on the right and check the db_owner checkbox in the bottom.  Click OK.
Try the query again.